# Confusion about atan vs atan2

Tags: limits, trigonometry, computational-mathematics, python, sagemath

I have the following function:

$$f(\omega) = \arctan\left(\frac{-\omega\cdot R / L}{-w^2 + 1/(C\cdot L)}\right)$$

When I try to plot it (`atan(f(w))`), I get the following:

[image]

This is clearly not an `atan` plot. I investigated a bit and found `atan2`. When I use it instead (`atan2(-w*R/L, -w**2 + 1/(C*L))`), I obtain:

[image]

That does look like a `atan` plot. **My question is**: is it correct to provide numerator and denominator as first and second arguments of `atan2` as I did?

Also, about `atan2`, my understanding is that the `tan` function doesn't have information about the sign of `cos` and `sin`, so it can't know if the angle comes from the first or third quadrant if the result is positive, or from the second or fourth quadrant if the result was negative. I don't understand very well why is this; how can not knowing the angle quadrants lead to the 'wrong' plot above?

### SageMath code to test the above

```
R = 100
L = 1.5e-3
C = 1.6e-9

abs_H(w) = 1/(C*L) / sqrt( (-w**2 + 1/(C*L))**2 + (R/L*w)**2 )
# phase_H(w) = atan( -(w*R/L) / (-w**2 + 1/(C*L)) ) * 180/pi 
phase_H(w) = atan2( -(w*R/L) , (-w**2 + 1/(C*L)) ) * 180/pi      # Notice atan2; otherwise it doesn't work

p = plot(abs_H, w, (10, 1e7), scale='loglog')
q = plot(phase_H, w, (10, 1e7), ymin=-180, scale='semilogx')
show(p)
print('')
show(q)
print('')
```

Comment: I don't think there's a universal convention on the argument order to atan2, but $y$, $x$ seems to be most common. Can you clarify what you find confusing about atan versus atan2? Your understanding of it looks correct, from what you wrote.

Comment: @AlexK In particular, I would like to know if the `atan2(a, b)` is equivalent to `atan(a/b)`, but with extra information about qudrants. Also, I don't understand how not knowing in which quadrant an angle is can produce such a 'weird' plot. Finally, I don't understand how lim(atan) when w->infinity can be 180 or -180 degrees.

Comment: I will ask about limits in a separated question.

Comment: @Martel yes, atan2 is equivalent to atan but with quadrants (also, it can deal with points on the $y$-axis). I'd recommend breaking your question down a bit before you go into the full function you've shown: if you don't quite get what atan2 is doing, looking at $f(\omega)$ first probably isn't going to help. It might be useful to start by thinking about what the graph of $y=\text{atan}(\tan(x))$ looks like. Why is it discontinuous? Where are the discontinuities? What if you restrict the domain to $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: You can also think of $\text{atan2}(y,x)$ as $\arg x+iy$

Comment: Careful because some implementations are `atan2(δx,δy)` and some are `atan2(δy,δx)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`φ = atan(m)` converts the slope `m` of a line into the bearing angle. If the slope is zero, the angle is zero (by convention). If the slope is `-∞` then the angle is `-π/2` and if the slope is `+∞` the angle is `+π/2`.

The result is limited to the 1st and 4th quadrants.

`φ = atan(dy,dx)` converts the direction defined by `(dx,dy)` into the bearing angle. If the direction points to the 2nd or 3rd quadrants (based on the signs of the arguments) then the angle result will vary between `-π` and `+π`.

Some environments define `φ = atan(dx,dy)` so care must be taken to get the correct order of arguments.

You must choose which function you need, as you pointed out when `m=dy/dx` the results are not always the same. There are cases when `atan2()` is preferred and cases where it is not. There are other cases you need positive angles only between `0` and `π` and there you use `φ = acos(dx/sqrt(dx**2+dy**2))`.

There is no universally proper way to do the conversion, as it depends on your assumptions related to the angle result.

Here is a graph of `atan(m)`

[image: fig1]

and the graph of `acos(1/sqrt(1+m^2))`

[image: fig2]

Both produce identical values for positive slope `m`, but the second one returns only the positive branch of angles for negative slope `m`.

and here is `atan2(dx=1, dy=m)`

[image: fig3]

which is identical to `atan()` as the direction information is lost since `dx` is always positive.